# Números complexos em C++

Tags: c++, matemática

Sou novo no C++ e gostaria de saber como usar números complexos sem ser da seguinte forma:

```
double real[2]={2,5};
double imaginario[2]{7,9};  
cout << "Soma: " << real[0]+real[1] << "+" << imaginario[0]+imaginario[1] << "i";
```

Há alguma library para isto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Há sim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    complex<double> a={2,7}, b={5,9};
    cout << "Soma: " << a+b;

}
```